# Is there any meta-approach for variable selection based of measures of similarity between each two variables?

Tags: feature-selection, algorithms, entropy, kullback-leibler, mutual-information

Is there any meta-approach ( or mayby I should say universal approach which works with different measures ) for variable selection which is based on similarity matrix which every entry `S[i,j]` contain value `M(X_i,X_j)` - mutual information, correlation, reg.coef., R2 of regression etc. between two variables ?

In the case of assymetric measures such as KL divergence and conditional enthropy it could be some approach based on algorithms like PageRank.